# Image Flip effect using prototype / scriptaculous javascript framework

Tags: prototypejs, javascript-framework

Here is the flip effect that I need: http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin

Is there any prototype / scriptaculous plugin doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think prototype has anything like that. A good library for visual effects is [Scriptaculous](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous). I know you haven't mentioned anything about Rails, but if that's what you're using, your layout probably already has includes for Scriptaculous. I think I can throw up an implementation for you if you're interested in using this library.

Comment: Oh! My client plans to use Prototype + Scriptaculous actually.
Is there any Scriptaculous plugin doing the same thing?